# First order moment of axial data

Tags: probability, expected-value, circular-statistics

The first moment of circular data (mod $2\pi$) is

$E(e^{i \theta}) = \int_0^{2\pi} P(\theta) e^{i \theta} d\theta$,

where $P(\theta)$ is some normalized probability distribution function for $\theta$, correct?

Now what if I have data that, rather than being circular (defined on mod $2 \pi$), is axial, aka defined on mod $\pi$, s.t. $P(\theta) = P(\theta + \pi)$?

Is there an analogous definition of the first moment?

Answer (score 1):

For axial data, say $ \omega \in [0, \pi) $, it is common to compute $ \theta = 2 \omega $ so that $\theta \in [0, 2 \pi)$ is circular. Then, we can perform any analysis in the circular statistics toolbox. Finally, we may backtransform results if desired for interpretation.

Therefore, little attention has gone into obtaining moments for axial data, or generating any analyses specifically for axial data, for that matter.

Keeping the "doubling the arrows" approach, we could compute the first moment of $ \theta = 2 \omega $ by first finding $ E( e^{i 2 \omega} ).$ If we take the argument of that moment, and halve it, we will have a first moment for our axial data, where the argument is the mean direction and the modulus is the resultant length.